Get values from 2 database statements with radio buttons
I am trying to connect two database statements via two radio buttons. As soon as I change the radio button value, these have to be retrieved again directly via the database.
I am currently trying to do this via HTML, JavaScript and Python. However, only one of the two statements is currently displayed.
js:
$("#id_base-0-show_null").change(function () {
        var show_null_value = document.querySelector('input[name=base-0-show_null]:checked').value;
        var checked_0 = document.getElementById('id_base-0-show_null_0').checked;
        var checked_1 = document.getElementById('id_base-0-show_null_1').checked;

        console.log(show_null_value, checked_0, checked_1);
       **currently doesn't do anything**

    });

exporter.py:
def get_last_values_of_target(self, target_type, target_name):
...

def get_zero_values_of_target(self, target_type, target_name):
...


manual_input.py:
def get_last_values_of_target(request):
    if is_ajax(request):
        target_type = int(request.POST['target_type'])
        target_name = request.POST['target_name']
        exporter = Exporter()
        exporter.station = target_type
        values = [exporter.get_last_values_of_target(target_type, target_name),
                  exporter.get_zero_values_of_target(target_type, target_name)]
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'values': values}), 'application/javascript')
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Not allowed")

template:
{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post" id="manual_input_form" name="manual_input_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="timeDiffer">
            {% for base_form in base_formset %}
                ***
                <div class="{% if base_form.non_field_errors %}error {% else %}showDiff{% endif %}">
                    <div>{{ base_form.show_differences.label_tag }}{{ base_form.show_differences }}</div>
                </div>
                {% if base_form.show_differences %}
                    <div class="{% if base_form.non_field_errors %}error {% else %}showNull{% endif %}">
                        <div class="flex">{% trans base_form.show_null.label_tag %}{{ base_form.show_null }}</div>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            <input type='hidden' id='source' name='source' value='Manual'>
        </div>
        {% for epoch_form in epochs_formset %}
            <table id="epoch_forms_table"
                   class="{% if counter >= 9 %}epoch_forms_table_long
                {% elif counter > 5 and counter < 9 %}epoch_forms_table_medium
                {% else %}epoch_forms_table{% endif %}">
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <tr class="title_row">
                    <th>{% autoescape off %}{% trans "Target name" %}{% endautoescape %}</th>
                    {% for k,v,i,z,b in sorted_title_list %}
                        {% if k == selected_item %}
                            <th>{{ z|capfirst }}</th>
                            {% if b|length == 1 %}
                                {% for key, value in b.items %}
                                    <th style="width: 50px;">
                                        <label for="unit_selector">
                                            <select class="master_select" id="unit_selector" name="unit_selector"
                                                    {% if b|length == 1 %}disabled{% endif %}>
                                                <option value="{{ value }}" id="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </label>
                                    </th>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% else %}
                                <th style="width: 40px"><label for="unit_selector">
                                    <select class="master_select" id="unit_selector" name="unit_selector">
                                        {% for key, value in b.items %}
                                            <option value="{{ value }}" id="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </label></th>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    <th class="last"></th>
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
            <tr class="value_row{% if epoch_form.errors %} error{% endif %}">
                <td><input id="id_epochs-0-target_name" name="epochs-0-target_name" class="group_left" type="text"
                           maxlength="100" size="16"></td>
                {% for k,v,i,z,b in sorted_title_list %}
                    {% if k == selected_item %}
                        <td><label><input id="id_epochs-0-{{ i }}" type="number" size="13" step="0.001"
                                          name="epochs-0-{{ i }}"></label></td>
                        {% if b|length == 1 %}
                            {% for key, value in b.items %}
                                <td class="{{ key }}_unit unit" id="{{ key }}"><label>{{ value }}</label></td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% else %}
                            {% for key, value in b.items %}
                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                    <td class="{{ key }}_unit unit" id="{{ key }}"><label>{{ value }}</label></td>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                <td><a href="#" class="button icon remove remove_row_button danger"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="last_value_row" class="last_value_row target_background_color">
                <td></td>
                {% for k,v,i,z,b in sorted_title_list %}
                    {% if k == selected_item %}
                        <td></td>
                        {% if b|length == 1 %}
                            {% for key, value in b.items %}
                                <td class="{{ key }}_unit unit" id="{{ key }}"><label>{{ value }}</label></td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% else %}
                            {% for key, value in b.items %}
                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                    <td class="{{ key }}_unit unit" id="{{ key }}"><label>{{ value }}</label></td>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="error_row">
                {% for field in epoch_form %}
                    <td>{{ field.errors }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
...
    </form>
{% endblock %}


EDIT:
I have added a radioCheck function to the existing JS function, which now fetches the data correctly, but the buttons do not really work yet.
I have also given the existing Manual_Input.py function the correct values.
function radioCheck(value_row, target_name) {
        var index = $(("#epoch_forms_table tr.value_row" || "#epoch_forms_table_medium tr.value_row" || "#epoch_forms_table_long tr.value_row")).index(value_row);
        var i;
        last_values[index] = [];
        const checked_0 = document.getElementById('id_base-0-show_null_0').checked;
        const checked_1 = document.getElementById('id_base-0-show_null_1').checked;
        $.post("/get_last_values_of_target/", {'target_type': selected_item, 'target_name': target_name},
            function (data) {
                if (checked_1 === true) {
                    if (data.values[0] != null) {
                        for (i = 0; i < data.values[0].length; i++) {
                            last_values[index].push(data.values[0][i]);
                        }
                    }
                    update_differences_of_row(value_row);
                } else if (checked_0 === true) {
                    if (data.values[1] != null) {
                        for (i = 0; i < data.values[1].length; i++) {
                            last_values[index].push(data.values[1][i]);
                        }
                    }
                    update_differences_of_row(value_row);
                }
            }, "json");
    }

Final Edit:
I figured it out!
I had to invoke the master-function in the change function. Now it works perfectly!
$("#id_base-0-show_null").change(function () {
        var value_row = $(("#epoch_forms_table tr.value_row" || "#epoch_forms_table_long tr.value_row" || "#epoch_forms_table_medium tr.value_row"));
        get_last_values_of_target(value_row);
});


Is the error in the python or the js?

there is no error. It just doesn't do anything, sadly...

What steps have you taken to debug it? Where and when are you executing these python functions? I think it would hep JS-wise, to show the rendered html rather than the code.

you use id_base-0-show_null in JavaScript but I don't see id_base-0-show_null in HTML.

The id_base-0-show_null is generated by Django itself (in the section DIV-"showNull"-Class in the "timeDiffer"-Class) of the base_form in base_formset (upper part)

In that case, please include the rendered html since the django doesn't seem to be the problem at the moment.
